# How to override loggedOut of the AuthenticatesUsers vendor file without directly editing it in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I understand that we should not directly edit the vendor files in Laravel, however I wish to know how I can override the loggedOut function of the trait AuthenticatesUsers so that I can perform some action when the user logs out.

Please could someone show me with some code snippet how this can be achieved.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this method in the LoginController or wherever else you're using that trait.

```
class LoginController {

    use AuthenticatesUser;

    public function loggedOut()
    {
        // Your custom code
    }
}
```